# Android Media box - remove top notification bar

Tags: android, notifications, removeall

I have a an android media box. It is the Measy B4A Amlogic s802 Quad core Cortex A9@ 2GHz (AML8726-M8) with Octo-core Mali-450MP GPU @ 600MHZ. OS is Android 4.4.2 Kitkat

I'm running a digital signage app on it and it is working fine but with one problem, which is the top notification bar. I can't seem to get rid of it. What I want is to completely remove it and launch the app at full screen. 
I'm not really a coder and I was able to root to the device with VRoot but I don't really know what to do next. Any ideas, please help.

thanks, 
Hussein

Comment: Ask your question plz in http://android.stackexchange.com/ this is coding questions only

Answer (score 0):

Simply write this in your manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check NoviSign App to get get performance for digital signage openinf a full screen on Android device 4.1 and above. [Here is the link](http://www.novisign.com/android/android-digital-signage-app/).